Failed to boot and tried updating plymouth but it didnt work
I had an error at the point of launching Plymouth on boot so I did the

sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(urname- r)

But it only says no space left on device so it won't update I tried

sudo update-initramfs -c -k $(urname- r) -k

And still nothing idk what to do there is no room on the drive apparently though I know they are empty and both 500gb space free at least

"I know they are empty" It would be better to edit your question, showing us the complete output of df -h

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
